# Show div with animation left to right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page where I want to show the div with slide in effect from left to right, but this is working opposite, right to left, not sure whats wrong here, can somebody please look?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#wrapper").animate({
    right: '100%'
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  Content goes here..
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to tell the jQuery to animate the element from `right: 0;` to `right: 100%;` which is moving the element distance 0 from right to 100% from right, so it is a right to left animation.

You probably would have to set the element initial state to `right: 100%` and jQuery animate to `right: 0` to get the effect

I have implemented a CSS version here that initalized `#wrapper { right: 100%; transition: 1s; }`

and set the position by applying class to it `#wrapper.animate { right: 0; }`

all you have to do is toggling the class of your element `$("#wrapper").addClass("animate");`

try it on https://jsfiddle.net/d1m9hrx5/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#wrapper").animate({ right: '0'}, 'slow');
});
```

```css
#wrapper{
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 101;
 top:0;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 10px;
 height:50px;
 width:100%;
 min-width:50px;
 background:red;
 right:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
   Content goes here..
</div>
```

or

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#wrapper").animate({ left: '100%'}, 'slow');
});
```

```css
#wrapper{
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 101;
 top:0;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 10px;
 height:50px;
 width:100%;
 min-width:50px;
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
   Content goes here..
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#main").animate({ right: '0'}, 'slow');
});
```

```css
#main{

 z-index: 999;
 top:0;
 color:#000;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 10px;
 height:50px;
 width:100%;
 min-width:50px;
 background:yellow;
 position: fixed;
 right:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
   Content goes here..
</div>
```